# Feh full screen shortcut

Tags: linux, ubuntu, feh

I was looking to setup fullscreen as shortcut for feh in my .config file but I can't find it anywhere.
I know that I can get full screen by using -F through command line but I was looking for a way to get full screen after feh is already opened.
ie, having the ability to toggle between regular screen and full screen.

Thanks for any help, really appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/derf/feh/blob/master/examples/keys

Comment: @PersianGulf, what I am asking isn't in there. I had already seen it before posting my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man feh`:

```
 v [toggle_fullscreen]
         Toggle fullscreen
```

In other words, you toggle between window and full screen with the key **<kbd>V</kbd>**, 'Vee'.

Example where the resolution will be the same in full screen mode, when you toggle between window and full screen

```
feh file.jpg
```

Example where the resolution in full screen mode will fit the screen (but the scale factors in x and y direction will be the same, there will be no distortion).

```
feh -Z file.png
```

---

**Edit:** This is different for `feh` between Ubuntu and Debian.

In Ubuntu **<kbd>v</kbd>**, vee, and in Debian **<kbd>f</kbd>**, eff, toggles fullscreen.

Comment: excellent, Thank you very much. I looked in the man pages as well but I guess I didn't pay enough attention. my bad.
let me see if I can change this v to f in my .config file, will accept your answer if I am able to.

Comment: I added below lines to my feh .config file but it seems to only show the filename on top of the image. toggle isn't working. :(( do you know any way to resolve this?

toggle_fullscreen
toggle_fullscreen f

Comment: @GAD3R: yes, my apologies, I typed v by mistake. it was supposed to be f but it's not working, it only displays the name of the file on top of the image. :(
do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The key **v** works for me with feh version  2.23.2 (in Lubuntu 18.,04.x) to toggle between window and full-screen. Which version of feh are you running? Is there a different key in the man page of that version?

Comment: Thanks @GAD3R, I will add that information into the answer :-)

Comment: @sodudus: yes, v key works perfectly fine but I want to change it to f.
that's what I am trying to do using .config.

Comment: @GAD3R:, I did, it's not working. I think that's because f is linked to save_filelist.
so I tried putting save_filelist to v and toggle_fullscreen to f. but it didn't work. :(

Comment: @sodudus, I am on Ubuntu (elementaryos), so for me v works perfectly fine but I am trying to change it to f as I am used to using f for full screen. :(

Comment: @Lucky Setting `save_filelist` to nothing and `toggle_fullscreen f` in `~/.config/feh/keys` works for me (feh version 2.18, Debian stretch)

Comment: @Freddy, I can confirm that it works for me. Both `save_filelist` to nothing and `toggle_fullscreen f` are needed for it to work. (There was no such file in my Lubuntu, so I had to create it.)

Comment: ok, I tried it but it's not working for me. I even put it both these lines on top just to make sure they don't mix up with my other settings but still it's not working. :((
I have all my keys mapped out in there so I think probably there is some conflict?

Comment: @Lucky, Maybe you can get used to toggle with v in this case ;-)

Comment: ok, I messed around with all my key mappings and now full screen is working. :))
now save_filelist is broken. :P 
even though I have save_filelist mapped to v, and toggle_filenames to t but t is doing the job of save_filelist. :P
but I don't really care much about that so it's all good. Thanks for everyone's help. :)) really appreciate it. :)